# Suggested edit counter always shows (1)

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I've often seen an **edit (1)** link next to post with a suggested edit, when hovered:

[image: Edit]

> 1 edit to this post is pending, please review it

---

Is it possible for a post to have more than one edits pending for review on it? I remember in the past, the number stated how many people voted on it.

---

After some testing, turns out it can't, so here's the findings:

- A post may only ever have one suggested edit at a time.
- When a post with a pending edit gets viewed by a low-rep user, the edit link is grayed out.
- The number **used to** mean "Total number of edit reviews this post had" (Basically, number of votes to approve + number of votes to reject).

For those reasons, the suggested edit will always show 1 (and by that implying that there could be more).

Are there plans of making a single post accept multiple suggest edits? Why was this changed in the first place?

Comment: Hmm, luckily there were a few suggested edits to be reviewed, so I could test. Seems you are right and things changed. The number _used_ to indicate the count of reviews the suggested edit already had.

Comment: Just noticed this one thanks to the tireless Community user who keep bumping unanswered questions! +1 and will start bounty as well to try lure some official attention.

Comment: I kind of doubt it, because if you click that, if you have 3K+, you'll be taken to the review.  If you don't, you'll be given a pending edit error.